# ListView only show 1 item from Array

Tags: android, arrays, listview

so lets just to the point, here is my code, and when i try to use Edittext and an button for saving data to listView, it works fine and all item show up on list view, but with a way that looks like in below, its only show one...

```
public class History extends Activity {

ListView show;
Button Home, toMap, Next;
EditText listTextMaker;
ArrayList<String> addArray = new ArrayList<String>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
    Home = findViewById(R.id.homeBtn);
    toMap = findViewById(R.id.backBtn);
    Next = findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);
    show = findViewById(R.id.textHistory);
    listTextMaker = findViewById(R.id.text);
    listTextMaker.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


    ConstructorBuilder();

}

public void Constructor(){

    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String dataHistory = prefs.getString("History", null );
    addArray.add(dataHistory);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(History.this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, addArray);
    show.setAdapter(adapter);


}

public void ConstructorBuilder(){
    Constractor();


    }

}
```

Comment: share a screenshot please

Comment: emu screenshot?

Comment: Your code above is getting a `String` from `SharedPreferences`, adding it to an empty array and showing it in a `ListView`. So, it is all natural that you only see 1 item in your list. I'd like to see a screenshot (from your UI) to understand what you are aiming to do?

Comment: in another layout i made a button that getting text from EditText, then i put it to SharedPreferences , then i get the EditText string in code below... im so sorry, but my laptop in problem that i cant get any screenshot..

Comment: at least share the code from that other activity. there is no way we could help without seeing code related to what you are asking

Answer (score 0):

you are adding only one data on your list:

```
String dataHistory = prefs.getString("History", null );
addArray.add(dataHistory);
```

If you want more than one data then just use below code:

```
    String dataHistory = prefs.getString("History", null );
    addArray.add(dataHistory);
    addArray.add(dataHistory);
    addArray.add(dataHistory);
    addArray.add(dataHistory);
    addArray.add(dataHistory);
```